# Is there a known fix for apps that suddenly stop delivering notifications for any obvious reason?

Tags: ios, applications, notifications

For several years now, I've noticed a really strange thing with notifications delivered from third-party apps on iOS - whereby they will just stop without any obvious reason. When checking within Settings/Notifications, nothing whatsoever has changed - all settings are as they should be. The immediately obvious steps (a device reboot and opening the app in question) don't resolve this - the only way of getting notifications back for the app in question is to remove it completely, and then reinstall it from the App Store. Whilst this isn't a big issue for apps that I'm only interested in notifications for (news apps are a good example), apps that require configuration are less ideal. Has anybody else noticed anything similar - and is there a known fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual recommendation is to uninstall the app and install it again, to give the push notification servers a chance to resynchronise.